# Using htaccess to allow deny php includes but not internet users

Tags: php, apache

Is it possible to set the .htaccess file to deny all users but allow includes such as PHP functions or CSS?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post .htaccess code for that, I need it too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that's one of the most popular uses of the .htaccess file.  Set up .htaccess to deny all.  Nobody can download the pages in that directory, but you can include php files from this directory in your other directories.  You can't really host css files in the directory and then deny all, because the user has to download these directly.  Same goes for images and javascript files. Basically, anything the client has to read shouldn't go in a "deny-all" directory, but stuff that only needs to be read by the server, like php includes are fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want something to be downloadable, then don't put it into a public-facing directory. Put those files in a different directory outside the webroot.

This way they don't get exposed if the .htaccess gets disabled somehow.